# PHP Compatibility Check Inside HTML

Tags: php, html, iphone

Is there anyway I can use this code inside a html file?

I have tried everything possible and can't seem to get it to work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks!

```
$isUDIDProtected=TRUE;
$compatibleVersions=array("8.1.1","8.1","8.0");
```

I was the top code for each php file

```
if ($isUDIDProtected)
{
        echo "<p style=\"color: red;\">This package is UDID protected! You must have your device registered to download this package</p>";
    }

    if ($compatibleVersions) 
{
        $uaString = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        if (preg_match("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/", $uaString)) {
            $version = preg_replace("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/","$2.$3.$4", $uaString);
        } else if (preg_match("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/", $uaString)) {
            $version = preg_replace("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/","$2.$3", $uaString);
        }
        if ($version) {
            if (in_array($version, $compatibleVersions)) {
                echo "<p style=\"color: green;\">This package is compatible with your iOS version :)</p>";
            } else {
                echo "<p style=\"color: #FFCC00\">This package is not comfirmed to work on your iOS version</p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

The html file is below

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li data-role="list-divider"><center>Compatibility</center></li>
<li><center>(show yes or no)</center></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is PHP code. It won't work inside an "html" file. You need to place it inside a PHP file (with corresponding php tags) and run it through the server.
Being said this, you could have a "compat.php" file with the code:

```
$compatibleVersions=array("8.1.1","8.1","8.0");

    if ($compatibleVersions) 
{
        $uaString = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        if (preg_match("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/", $uaString)) {
            $version = preg_replace("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/","$2.$3.$4", $uaString);
        } else if (preg_match("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/", $uaString)) {
            $version = preg_replace("/(.*) OS ([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) (.*)/","$2.$3", $uaString);
        }
        if (isset($version) && in_array($version, $compatibleVersions)) {
           echo "<p style=\"color: green;\">This package is compatible with your iOS version :)</p>";
        } else {
           echo "<p style=\"color: #FFCC00\">This package is not comfirmed to work on your iOS version</p>";
        }
    }
```

Then, inside another file "htmlPage.php", something like:

```
<?php 
$isUDIDProtected=TRUE;
if ($isUDIDProtected)
{
        echo "<p style=\"color: red;\">This package is UDID protected! You must have your device registered to download this package</p>";
die();
    }
?>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li data-role="list-divider"><center>Compatibility</center></li>
<li><center><?php include "compat.php" ?></center></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the htmlPage.php file be placed inside the .html file?

Comment: Nope, "htmlPage.php" should be a page itself. If you place it inside a "html" file, your code won't work because it won't know how to parse PHP code. It will just show "<?php include "compat.php" ?>" as plain text.

Comment: Than what would i place inside my html file to load the two echo's in compat.php

Comment: You shouldn't use a "html" file. You should have a php file, for example, the one i mentioned "htmlPage.php" and then include the "compat.php" file inside it as i showed in my example. You can write html code inside php file if you don't enclose the code in php tags "<?php ?>". So, if you create the two files i mentioned and run "htmlPage.php" from your server (for example: "localhost/htmlPage.php" and not just by double clicking it and running on browser because it won't parse php), it should work.

Comment: I would like the top code to be placed in each php file and checks if it is compatible with the second code...

Comment: The htmlPage.php will not display the two echo in the other files though

Comment: Just noticed that one of the ifs uses "$versions" and that variable doesn't exist. That is why it is not printing anything. It does never enter to that if block.

Comment: I got this code off of the internet so it's probably not finished... What code do i need to add now? Again thanks so much for helping me with this

Comment: Check my edited answer and dismiss my last comment (the one about "$versions"). I got confused and read something that wasn't there. Sorry.

Comment: How would i add all of my html code into a php file?

Comment: Use the two files i mentioned. All the code is there.

Comment: Is there anyway the php echo could use my html css?

Comment: Hmm i am not understanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the php code under php opening and closing tags in html code according to if else construct situation.

Comment: Yes its true i was assuming the code has been written into the php extension file. Not in the file who is having .html extension. The above php code would only work in case if its having .php extension not the file having other extensions. So make sure you are writing code inside the php extension file moreover we can also make use of .htaccess file to show the php file to .html in web browser.